# Changing input element color

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to figure out the form structure of twitter bootstrap. I want to change to a specific validation state http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-control-states (scroll down a little bit) I have this form:

```
<form class="form-signin" id="registerForm">
   <input class="form-control input-sm" type="email" placeholder="E-mail">
   <input class="form-control input-sm" type="text" maxlength="30" placeholder="Username (6-30 characters)">
   <input class="form-control input-sm" type="password" maxlength="30" placeholder="Password (6-30 characters)">
   <button id="registerButton" class="btn-small"><b>Register</b></button>
</form>
```

What attribute should i alter to be able to get a specific validation color on an inputfield?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean, what should you do if you want different color on input field, then you should add some of the classes provided on parent containing input field.
For example, `<div class="has-warning"><input type="text" class="form-control"></div>`.

"Validation states

Bootstrap includes validation styles for error, warning, and success states on form controls. To use, add .has-warning, .has-error, or .has-success to the parent element. Any .control-label, .form-control, and .help-block within that element will receive the validation styles."